# Регулярное выражение dd.mm.yyyy на С

Tags: c

Недавно начала изучать С  и столкнулась с проблемой использования регулярного выражения для даты и не могу найти толкового описания как их правильно использовать.

Задумка такова:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    //system("clear"); // очистка консоли
    int per_bth_date;
    printf("Введите дату рождения: ");
    scanf("%d", &per_bth_date);

    if (per_bth_date != regex) {
        printf("error\n");
    } else if (per_bth_date == regex) {
        printf("good\n");
    } else{
        printf("full error\n");
    }

}
```

Где `regex` - переменная хранящая регулярное выражение / регулярное выражение

Необходима проверка на валидность ввода такого формата - `dd.mm.yyyy`

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните подробней в состоит проблема.

Comment: Вам надо обратить внимание на две такие функции `strftime()` и `strptime()`. Также не забывайте, что процессы могут быть запущеными в разных локализациях (`man locale`). Формат даты описывается стандартом ISO 8601.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы рекомендовал чуть плотнее пройтись по основам языка, потому что у вас большие пробелы. По текущему коду можно дать несколько советов, но помимо советов нужна база.

Смотрите, вот здесь:

```
int per_bth_date;
printf("Введите дату рождения: ");
scanf("%d", &per_bth_date);
```

Вы описали *целое число* и просите ввести тоже *целое*, о чём свидетельствует формат `%d`. Но вам нужна *строка* и вводить тоже надо строку.

```
char per_bth_date[200];
printf("Введите дату рождения: ");
scanf("%s", per_bth_date);
```

"C" относится к **низкоуровневым** языкам, поэтому управление памятью - на вас. Вы должны сами определить, сколько символов максимально сможете прочитать. Например, 200 с запасом. При вводе используется формат `%s` и удаляется символ "амперсанд" ( `&` ) из параметра `&per_bth_date`.

Этот код нельзя назвать корректным, потому что переполнение буфера всё равно возможно, но он , по крайней мере, будет запускаться и работать до тех пор, пока количество введённых символов не превысит 200.

В стандартную библиотеку "С" не входит обработка регулярных выражений. Можно поискать существующую библиотеку, например, [ту же](http://www.pcre.org/), которая используется в "Perl". Но для такой небольшой задачи вы можете написать проверку вручную

```
int isdate(const char* date)
{
    if (!isdigit(*date++))
      return 0;

    if (!isdigit(*date++))
      return 0;

    if (*date++ != '.')
      return 0;

    if (!isdigit(*date++))
      return 0;

    if (!isdigit(*date++))
      return 0;

    if (*date++ != '.')
      return 0;

    if (!isdigit(*date++))
      return 0;

    if (!isdigit(*date++))
      return 0;

    if (!isdigit(*date++))
      return 0;

    return isdigit(*date++);
}
```

Comment: уж лучше тогда регулярки из плюсов использовать

Answer (score 0):

Максимально упрощённый пример с использованием библиотеки PCRE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pcre.h>

#define DATE_SIZE 11

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  pcre *pattern;
  const char *error_str;
  int error_offset;
  int matches[1];

  pattern = pcre_compile("^\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}$", 0, &error_str, &error_offset, NULL);

  if(pattern == NULL) {
    printf("Could not compile: %s\n", error_str);
    return 1;
  }

  char str[DATE_SIZE];
  fgets(str, DATE_SIZE, stdin);

  int r = pcre_exec(pattern, NULL, str, strlen(str), 0, 0, matches, 1);

  pcre_free(pattern);

  if (r < 0)
    puts("Invalid date");
  else
    puts("Valid date");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```